# Is there any way to load files to Chrome when debugging node scripts

Tags: node.js, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

Currently it's possible to debug node scripts using Chrome as described [here](https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27). However, if I run like this:

```
node --inspect --debug-brk myscript
```

It will only load `myscript` to the browser and I'll be able to put breakpoints in this file. But suppose that `myscript` requires `anotherscript` and I want to put a breakpoint in this script. I don't see how this can be done since Chrome inspector only loaded `myscript`.

Is there any way to load a file into Chrome inspector before this files is required in the script and Chrome loads it by itself?

I'm currently modifying sources and put `debugger;` statement there which works. But I was thinking that should be something more apt for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it's currently not possible.

One possible solution to avoid modifying sources is to put a breakpoint at the end of the script. In this way the Chrome by the time the breakpoint is reached and the execution is paused Chrome will have loaded all relevant files. You can then open any file using `Ctrl+P` and put a breakpoint there. Chrome keeps breakpoints between sessions if you use  `Open dedicated Chrome DevTool for Node` option:

[image]

Then simply restart you node application. See more details in the [This will make you more efficient at debugging Webpack unspecified build errors](https://blog.angularindepth.com/this-will-make-you-more-efficient-at-debugging-wepback-unspecified-build-errors-6392850caed9) article.